# How to split a long file and printout to different text files by Perl?

Tags: perl, text, hash, split

I have a long list text file with 3 column.

The input file:

```
XIGO    XIGO_24480  Xigou  
XIGO    XIGO_24481  Xigou  
XOLO    XOLO_Z1E01  Xoloitzcuintle  
XOLO    XOLO_Z1G01  Xoloitzcuintle  
YORK    TYo_0GT393  Yorkshire Terrier  
YORK    TYo_0GT394  Yorkshire Terrier
```

I want the output text files with the number-tags. The list split by the 3rd column.

File_1.txt

```
XIGO    XIGO_24480   
XIGO    XIGO_24481
```

File_2.txt

```
XOLO    XOLO_Z1E01   
XOLO    XOLO_Z1G01
```

File_3.txt

```
YORK    TYo_0GT393   
YORK    TYo_0GT394
```

I try to split the file in Perl with hash function. However, I still can not get the right files.

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;
use warnings;

my $input = 'File_List_1.txt';
my %results;
my $out;
my $FID;
my $IID;
my $Breed;
my $results;
my @array;
my $index=0;

open(my $fh, '<', $input) or die "cannot open input file: $!";


 while (<$fh>) {
   chomp;
   my ($FID, $IID, $Breed) = split '\t', $_;
   $results{$Breed}{$IID} = $FID;
 }

 for my $values (keys %results) {
 open (my $out, '>', 'File_',"$index.txt") or die "cannot open input file: $!";

 for my $values_1 (keys %{$results{$values}}){
   print $out, join ("\t" , map {$results{$values}->{$values_1},$values_1} keys%results);
 }
 close $out;
```

Are there any suggestions for me? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for:

- read input lines from STDIN

  - split into first part + key
  - if we haven't seen key before

    - open new file for writing, using index in the file name
    - store file handle in hash using key.
    - increase index by one
  - get file handle from hash with key and write first part to it
- close all open file handles when we're done

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $index = 1;
my %seen;

while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    my($start, $key) = /^(\S+\s+\S+)\s+(.+)\s*$/;

    unless ($seen{$key}) {
        # new key detected, we need to open new file
        open(my $fh, '>', "File_${index}.txt")
            or die "can't open new file: $!\n";
        $seen{$key} = $fh;
        $index++;
    }

    my $fh = $seen{$key};
    print $fh "${start}\n";
}

# close files
close $_ foreach (values %seen);

exit 0;
```

Test run:

```
$ perl dummy.pl <dummy.txt
$ cat File_1.txt 
XIGO    XIGO_24480
XIGO    XIGO_24481
$ cat File_2.txt 
XOLO    XOLO_Z1E01
XOLO    XOLO_Z1G01
$ cat File_3.txt 
YORK    TYo_0GT393
YORK    TYo_0GT394
```

**NOTE:** for completeness sake: the above solution will run into `too many open files` error on a standard Linux machine if your input has more than ~1000 keys. You'll have to use `ulimit` to increase the limits, or pre-sort the data to be able to use the optimized version below. Or keep all data in memory and write the files after the end of the loop.

---

**EDIT:** this can be optimized if you are sure that keys don't repeat in the input file, e.g.

```perl
my $fh;    
while (<STDIN>) {
    chomp;
    my($start, $key) = /^(\S+\s+\S+)\s+(.+)\s*$/;

    unless ($seen{$key}++) {
        # new key detected, we need to open new file
        if ($fh) {
            close($fh) or die "close: $!\n";
        }
        open($fh, '>', "File_${index}.txt")
            or die "can't open new file: $!\n";
        $index++;
    }

    print $fh "${start}\n";
}

# make sure to close last open file
close($fh) or die "close: $!\n";
```

I don't know what your real input data looks like, but if order of the output isn't relevant then you could pre-sort the input data in bash for this optimized version with:

```bash
$ sort -t $'\t' -k 3 dummy.txt | perl dummy.pl
```

---

**EDIT2** if you want to keep your original `split()` approach:

```perl
# remove trailing whitespace
s/\s+$//;
my($FID, $IID, $key) = split('\t', $_);
...
print $fh "${FID}\t${IID}\n";
```

Answer (score 1):

Though awk is not tagged, it works best in this case. If you want to try, here is how you do it

```
$ cat victor.txt
XIGO    XIGO_24480  Xigou
XIGO    XIGO_24481  Xigou
XOLO    XOLO_Z1E01  Xoloitzcuintle
XOLO    XOLO_Z1G01  Xoloitzcuintle
YORK    TYo_0GT393  Yorkshire Terrier
YORK    TYo_0GT394  Yorkshire Terrier
$ awk ' { curr=$1; if(prev!=curr) { x++ } print $1, $2, "File_" x ".txt" ; prev=curr } ' victor.txt
XIGO XIGO_24480 File_1.txt
XIGO XIGO_24481 File_1.txt
XOLO XOLO_Z1E01 File_2.txt
XOLO XOLO_Z1G01 File_2.txt
YORK TYo_0GT393 File_3.txt
YORK TYo_0GT394 File_3.txt
$ ls File_1.txt File_2.txt File_3.txt
/bin/ls: cannot access File_1.txt: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: cannot access File_2.txt: No such file or directory
/bin/ls: cannot access File_3.txt: No such file or directory
```

The above awk prints the results we needed. awk can redirect output to files

```
$ awk ' { curr=$1; if(prev!=curr) { x++ } print $1, $2  > "File_" x ".txt" ; prev=curr } ' victor.txt
$ ls File_1.txt File_2.txt File_3.txt
File_1.txt  File_2.txt  File_3.txt
$ cat File_1.txt
XIGO XIGO_24480
XIGO XIGO_24481
$ cat File_2.txt
XOLO XOLO_Z1E01
XOLO XOLO_Z1G01
$ cat File_3.txt
YORK TYo_0GT393
YORK TYo_0GT394
$
```